# Writing to one column using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to write the values of the list  `values` only on column `A` of the new workbook, for example:

```
 a1 = 1
 a2 = 2
 a3 = 3
```

etc. etc. but right now I get this:

```
a1 = 1   b1 = 2  c1= 3 d1= 4
a1 = 1   b1 = 2  c1= 3 d1= 4
a1 = 1   b1 = 2  c1= 3 d1= 4
```

My code:

```
# create new workbook and worksheet

values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
wb = Workbook(write_only = True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()

for row in range(0, len(values)):
    ws.append([i for i in values])

wb.save('newfile.xlsx')
```

this code above fills all the cells in range `A1:A15` to `O1:O15`
I only want to fill the values in column `A1:A15`

Comment: Why do you make a copy of `values`? Why not just do `ws.append([values])`? Also, if you do need to copy a list, the usual ways to do it are `items = list(values)` or `items = values[:]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Not yet tested, but I would think*

Tested-- you have a syntax error also; substitute 'row' for 'i'.  But the following works.

```
for row in range(0, len(values)):
    ws.append([row])
```

Comment: im using a list comprehension, why would i use "row" instead of "i" in my list comprehension. i want to add the values inside the `values` list,  
this appends the enumerate row integers no? what if my list of values changes from a list of integers to a list of strings?

Comment: @joseph yes, I've edited the suggestion. xlsx is a row-based format which is why we have the `append` method. Otherwise `ws.cell(row=1, col=idx, value=value)` can be used but `append` is compacter.

Comment: great, i tested and `ws.append([row])` works for adding numbers `0-len(values)`, but what if my `values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]` change to `values = ['hello', 'abc', 'redr']`? thats where im stuck :/

Comment: i got it! i was running the list comprehension inside the `for` loop. i'll edit my post with the correct input, thanks guys!

Comment: Hey guys!  I am working on a script with lists +20,000 in length.  I want to write list 1 to column A, which is fine, but how do I start writing list 2 to Column B?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create nested list to append the values in column, refer below code.

from openpyxl import Workbook

values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet()

newlist = [[i] for i in values]

print(newlist)

for x in newlist:
ws.append(x)

wb.save('newfile.xlsx')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).